# Need help connecting two virtual machines together

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, sql-server-2016, windows-server-2012-r2, vmware-workstation

I am running two virtual machines on my local computer (Windows Server 2012 R2 and Windows 10 running on vmware workstation 12). My Server 2012 R2 has SQL Server 2016 Developers edition on there and I have Windows 10. Both of them have SSMS 17.7 on them. I am trying to connect to the server on my Windows 10 machine via SSMS. I tried authenticating them, but the Windows 10 VM does not show up. Even when I try to map or even UNC path into any of them, nothing shows up (on both ends). Now, I have tried bridged connection and serial port for both of them and that does not seem to work. Does anyone have any ideas on what may be the problem or can give me a link to do this in? I have tried this youtube link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1&v=GUsyEJda-E0 and VMWare's official site:https://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_devices_serial_2vms.html  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't say I've worked much with VM Workstation however in VirtualBox the network needs to be NAT'd in order for the VM's to obtain a IP Address from your router which would then give them routing to each other

Comment: I initially have tried that in the first place (to obtain internet for both of them), but when i do that, I get the "Windows cannot access \\ipAddress\anyfolder."